# Dragging Excel formula involving INDIRECT

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office-2007

`=INDIRECT("'"&$A4&"'!E4")`

This is supped to use the value from cell E4 of the sheet with name found in A4. In fact it works. But when I drag this formula across multiple columns/rows, the `A4` updates to different columns but the `E4` doesn't... I think because it's in a string.

How can I make this work, everything I try gives me !REF?

Comment: In what cell are you putting this formula? Using `row()` and `column()` seems appropriate.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. This is just like having `='John'!E4` in a cell A1 ... and when I drag that across other columns it should change to `='John'!F4`, `='John'!G4`, etc

Comment: Please, post where the formula is, the contents of A4, E4 and whatever is relevant to the formula.

Comment: The formula is in a sheet 'target'. so target A4 contains the name of another sheet to use. and E4 is the cell in that sheet to lookup. In target, each row shows data from a different sheet based on value in A column

Answer (score 5):

Try using `CELL` function like this

`=INDIRECT("'"&$A4&"'!"&CELL("address",E4))`

That converts E4 to text for use in INDIRECT function but will still update when you drag across/down

Answer (score 2):

Well, you weren't very clear in your comment, so I guess it'll be simpler if I give something and you adjust it for your needs.

I'm assuming that you have the formula `=INDIRECT("'"&$A4&"'!E4")` in sheet `Target` and cell `A1`.

```
=INDIRECT("'"&$A4&"'!E4")
```

You can change it to:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&$A4&"'!"&CHAR(96+COLUMN()+4)&ROW()+3)
```

`COLUMN()` returns the column in which the formula is. Here, since the formula is in cell A1, `COLUMN()` returns 1.

`ROW()` acts the same way, but with the number of rows, and will return 1 as well here.

`CHAR(96+COLUMN()+4)` will return `CHAR(96+1+4)` in this case which is the letter `E`.

`ROW()+3` will return `1+3` which is `4`.

Concatenating everything will give you E4.

When you copy/paste this formula in B1, you'll get:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&$B4&"'!"&CHAR(96+COLUMN()+4)&ROW()+3)
```

`COLUMN()` now returns 2 because it's in the second column and `CHAR()` will return `F`.

Since the row is the same, you get `4`, so that the referenced cell becomes `F4`.

Comment: This works, I independently got something very similar but I assumed there was a better way than manually constructing the column letter! Clearly not, good to see it confirmed.